# Conditional operations on numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I'm new to NumPy, and I've encountered a problem with running some conditional statements on numpy arrays. Let's say I have 3 numpy arrays that look like this:

a:

```
[[0, 4, 4, 2],
 [1, 3, 0, 2],
 [3, 2, 4, 4]]
```

b:

```
[[6, 9, 8, 6],
 [7, 7, 9, 6],
 [8, 6, 5, 7]]
```

and, c:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I have a conditional statement for a and b in which I would like to use the value of b (if the conditions of a and b are met) to calculate the value of c:

```
c[(a > 3) & (b > 8)]+=b*2
```

I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,4)
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

I would like the output of c to look as follows:

```
[[0, 18, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Upvotes for everyone as they all worked. I accepted the answer from @Psidom for np.where as it made the most sense to me and ran in the quickest amount of time (my actual script will run these conditionals a couple million times)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where`:

```
np.where((a > 3) & (b > 8), c + b*2, c)
#array([[ 0, 18,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Or arithmetically:

```
c + b*2 * ((a > 3) & (b > 8))
#array([[ 0, 18,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that **you mask the receiving part**, but do **not mask the sender part**. As a result:

```
c[(a > 3) & (b > 8)]+=b*2
# ^ 1x1 matrix        ^3x4 matrix
```

The dimensions are not the same. Given you want to perform **element-wise addition** (based on your example), you can simply add the slicing to the right part as well:

```
c[(a > 3) & (b > 8)]+=b[(a > 3) & (b > 8)]*2
```

or make it more efficient:

```
mask = (a > 3) & (b > 8)
c[mask] += b[mask]*2
```

Answer (score 3):

A slight change in the numpy expression would get the desired results:

```
c += ((a > 3) & (b > 8)) * b*2
```

Here First I create a mask matrix with boolean values, from `((a > 3) & (b > 8))`, then multiply the matrix with `b*2` which in turn generates a `3x4` matrix which can be easily added to `c`