# Adding condition to python function

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to make a small example for my students plotting the electron density of an atom as a function of distance from center, r, nuclear charge, Z, and Ionization energy, I.

The density is given by:

```
rho = exp(-2*Z*r) for r < r_cut
```

and

```
rho = exp(-2*sqrt(2*I)*r (for a specified value of r_cut, I and Z).
```

I wanted to do it in a smart Pythonic way and not just loop over all r:s. I tried to do according to the code in the bottom but received an error:

> ----> 5     if r < r_cut:
>        6         return exp(-2*z*r)
>        7     else:
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Any suggestions? 
(I have tried to search but could not find a good answer. If there is already one please direct me.)

```
r = linspace(0, 3., 100)

kjmol = 3.8088e10-4
def rho_r(r, r_cut, z, I):
    if r < r_cut:
        return exp(-2*z*r)
    else:
        return exp(-2*sqrt(2*I)*r)

plot(r, rho_r(r, r_cut=3., z=2., I=2372*kjmol))
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional operations on numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540224/conditional-operations-on-numpy-arrays)

Comment: There are lots of answers explaining this ambiguity value error.  `x<3` for an array produces multiple True/False values, an array of such.  But an `if` only works with one value.  There's no implied loop in a `if` branching.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this should do the trick for you:

```py
import numpy as np
r = np.linspace(0, 3., 100)

kjmol = 3.8088e10-4
def rho_r(r, r_cut, z, I):
    res=np.exp(-2*np.sqrt(2*I)*r)
    res[r < r_cut]=np.exp(-2*z*r[r<r_cut])
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this...

```
def rho_r(r, r_cut, z, I):
    rho = where((r < r_cut), exp(-2*z*r), exp(-2*sqrt(2*I)*r) )
    return rho
```

I wonder if this is to weird