# Python: How to change values of one column bases on condition of other?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. There are about 50 columns and 50000 rows. If one colums has a row that

```
str.contains('certain response')
```

I want to change the other column response to

```
'NA'
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your question: Do mean the following? If the value of one column contains "certain response" you want to change the value of another column to "NA" (in the same row).

Comment: Yes! I have this so far, it isn't working. df = df.loc[df.column1.contains('certain response'), 'column 2'] = 'NaN'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python PANDAS, change one value based on another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226488/python-pandas-change-one-value-based-on-another-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for condition and if need replace by `NaN` use `np.nan`:

```
df.loc[df.column1.str.contains('certain response'), 'column 2'] = np.nan
```

Or use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html), if `True` get `NaN`s:

```
df['column 2'] = df['column 2'].mask(df.column1.str.contains('certain response'))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['certain response','certain response 2','aaa'],
                   'column 2':[2,3,4]})
df['column 2'] = df['column 2'].mask(df.column1.str.contains('certain response'))
print (df)
  column 2             column1
0       NaN    certain response
1       NaN  certain response 2
2       4.0                 aaa
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that. I got an error: TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: Need `na` parameter - `df.column1.str.contains('certain response', na=False)`

Comment: Got it! Thank you!