# How can I change the value in a Pandas cell based on the value of another one?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe called 'df' that looks like this

```
Col1   TF      
1      False
2      True
2      False
2      False
2      False
3      False
4      False
```

And I would like for every row in to have a 'TF' value of True if Col1 = 2. The desired output for df is

```
Col1   TF      
1      False
2      True
2      True
2      True
2      True
3      False
4      False
```

I haven't found a method that works for me yet

Comment: `df['TF'] = df['Col1'] == 2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change one value based on another value in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226488/change-one-value-based-on-another-value-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

You could use numpy.where to check Col1 and modify the TF column:

```
df.TF = np.where(df.Col1 == 2, True, False)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jose. If you put four spaces before text, it will be formatted as code (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)