# Add a column to a dataframe based on the contents of a string in another colum

Tags: python, pandas

My data-frame looks like this

```
Year   Event 
2015   Men's 100m 
2016   Men's Archery
2016   Women's Archery
2017   Men's Weightlifting
1998   Women's 100m
2002   Women's Sailing
```

I would like to add a new column to this data-frame that identifies if it is a male of female event. The desired output would look like this:

```
Year   Event               Gender
2015   Men's 100m          M
2016   Men's Archery       M
2016   Women's Archery     F
2017   Men's Weightlifting M
1998   Women's 100m        F
2002   Women's Sailing     F
```

Is this even possible? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226488/change-one-value-based-on-another-value-in-pandas) answer your question?

Comment: `df['Gender'] = df['Event'].str[0]`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pd.Series.str` functions -

```
df['Gender'] = df.Event.str.contains('Men').apply(lambda x: 'M' if x else 'F')
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy was would be:

```py
df['Gender'] = ['M' if 'Men' in row['Event'] else 'F' for _,row in df.iterrows()]
```