# changing the value of a field based on on the value of other fields

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe called 'qtm' that looks like the following:

| Name | Strength | Weakness |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Voltron | NaN | Flower |
| Joe | punch | candy |
| Voltron | Speed | Time |

I want the Python equivalent of the SQL code below:

```
UPDATE qtm
SET Strength = 'Fire' 
WHERE Name = 'Voltron' AND Strength = 'NaN'
```

So I could get the following dataframe back:

| Name | Strength | Weakness |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Voltron | Fire | Flower |
| Joe | punch | candy |
| Voltron | Speed | Time |

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
qtm.loc[qtm['Name'] == 'Voltron' & qtm['Strength'] == 'NaN', 'Strength']='Fire'
```

I tried the following solutions but ultimately couldn't get it to work:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226488/change-one-value-based-on-another-value-in-pandas]

&

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980121/change-value-of-a-column-based-on-another-column?noredirect=1&lq=1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parentheses with test missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
qtm.loc[(qtm['Name'] == 'Voltron') & (qtm['Strength'].isna()), 'Strength']='Fire'
```

Or use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for set `NaN`s by mask:

```
#one condition () not necessary
m = qtm['Name'] == 'Voltron'
qtm.loc[m, 'Strength'] = qtm.loc[m, 'Strength'].fillna('Fire')
```

Comment: this worked. would equating df == ‘not avail’ also work if for instance the Strength value I were looking for was ‘not avail’ instead of NaN?

Comment: @ThatGuyXY - yes, then use `(qtm['Strength']== 'not avail')`