# 2 column conditional and then

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have 2 columns in the same data frame as shown:

```
Col1    Col2
YES     NO
YES     NO
YES     YES
YES     NO
YES     YES
        YES
        YES
        NO
        NO
```

I need to create a conditional:
if Col1 == "YES" and Col2 == "NO" then COL2 = "YES",
Meaning: if column 1 is "YES" and Column 2 is "NO" then COLUMN 2 is "YES"

I was trying with:

```
if df_db['Marketo LSC_x'] == "YES" and df_db['Marketo LSC_y'] == 'NO':
    df_db['Marketo LSC_y'] = 'YES'
```

but is not working, is giving me this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Why do you even need to check `col2`? Just change `col2` to `YES` whenever `col1` is `YES`. If it was already `YES`, no harm done... `df.loc[df.col1 == "YES", "col2"] = "YES"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change one value based on another value in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226488/change-one-value-based-on-another-value-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, [Logical operators for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas).

---

Try this:

```py
criteria_1 = df_db['Marketo LSC_x'] == "YES"
criteria_2 = df_db['Marketo LSC_y'] == 'NO'

criteria = criteria_1 & criteria_2

df_db.loc[criteria, 'Marketo LSC_y'] = 'YES'
```

Comment: I tried and it gave me this error: TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]

Comment: I changed my answer because of my mistake. Let me know if you fix this error.