# How to make values in one column dependent on another?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have one column called "A" with only values 0 or 1. I have another column called "B". If column A value=0, I want the column B value to equal "dog". If column A value=1, I want the column B value to equal "cat".

**Sample DataFrame column:**

```
print(df)
   A
0  0
1  1
```

Is there anyway to fill the B column as such without a for loop?

**Desired:**

```
print(df)
   A  B
0  0  Cat
1  1  Dog
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research, and what were your results? Please [edit] to include a [mcve]

Comment: See [Change one value based on another value in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226488/change-one-value-based-on-another-value-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Can Simply can try Below using `map`...

### Sample Data

```
print(df)
   A
0  0
1  1
2  0
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  0
7  0
8  1
```

### Result:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map({0:'Cat', 1:'Dog'})
print(df)
   A    B
0  0  Cat
1  1  Dog
2  0  Cat
3  1  Dog
4  1  Dog
5  1  Dog
6  0  Cat
7  0  Cat
8  1  Dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please post your research and minimal reproducible code. See comments

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': [0, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
m = {0: ("Dog"), 1: ("Cat")}
df['B'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: m[x])
```