# How to replace all occurrences in a column with a given value based on a condition applied to a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

| Name | Code | Amount | Seller |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sildenafil 1045 | VGRA | 32 | Rite Aid |
| Ibuprofen 378 | ADVL | 209 | CVS |
| Paracetamol | PCTML | 87 | Keystone |
| Aspirin 9852 | DISP | 372 | Rite Aid |
| Ibuprofen 1992 | MOTR | 87 | Walgreens |
| Benadryl | BDRL | 120 | CVS |
| Aspirin 0541 | SPRN | 197 | H Mart |
| Sildenafil 002 | VIAG | 12 | Omnicare |
| Ibuprofen 378 | ADVL | 301 | Keystone |
| Paracetamol | PCTML | 673 | Walgreens |
| Ibuprofen 1992 | MOTR | 87 | Omnicare |
| Sildenafil 1045 | VGRA | 45 | H Mart |
| Benadryl | BDRL | 111 | Keystone |
| Aspirin 9852 | DISP | 285 | CVS |
| Sildenafil 002 | VIAG | 79 | Rite Aid |
| Aspirin 0541 | SPRN | 431 | Omnicare |

where df.Code.unique() = [VGRA, ADVL, PCTML, DISP, MOTR, BDRL, SPRN, VIAG]

I want to identify the medicines of the same 'Name' (but different ending numbers) with the same 'Code'

Ex. 'Ibuprofen 378' and 'Ibuprofen 1992' have two different codes- 'ADVL' and 'MOTR' respectively. I want to replace all instances of 'MOTR' with 'ADVL'. Same for Sildenafil and Aspirin and any other drugs with the same coding situation. The output should look like this:

| Name | Code | Amount | Seller |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sildenafil 1045 | VGRA | 32 | Rite Aid |
| Ibuprofen 378 | ADVL | 209 | CVS |
| Paracetamol | PCTML | 87 | Keystone |
| Aspirin 9852 | DISP | 372 | Rite Aid |
| Ibuprofen 1992 | ADVL | 87 | Walgreens |
| Benadryl | BDRL | 120 | CVS |
| Aspirin 0541 | DISP | 197 | H Mart |
| Sildenafil 002 | VGRA | 12 | Omnicare |
| Ibuprofen 378 | ADVL | 301 | Keystone |
| Paracetamol | PCTML | 673 | Walgreens |
| Ibuprofen 1992 | ADVL | 87 | Omnicare |
| Sildenafil 1045 | VGRA | 45 | H Mart |
| Benadryl | BDRL | 111 | Keystone |
| Aspirin 9852 | DISP | 285 | CVS |
| Sildenafil 002 | VGRA | 79 | Rite Aid |
| Aspirin 0541 | DISP | 431 | Omnicare |

where df.Code.unique() = [VGRA, ADVL, PCTML, DISP, BDRL]

I cannot figure out how to do this, the only thing I've managed is generating a third variable using

> df.Name_Code = df.Name.astype(str).str[:5]

| Name | Code | Amount | Seller | Name_Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sildenafil 1045 | VGRA | 32 | Rite Aid | SILDE |
| Ibuprofen 378 | ADVL | 209 | CVS | IBUPR |
| Paracetamol | PCTML | 87 | Keystone | PARAC |
| Aspirin 9852 | DISP | 372 | Rite Aid | ASPIR |
| Ibuprofen 1992 | ADVL | 87 | Walgreens | IBUPR |
| Benadryl | BDRL | 120 | CVS | BENAD |
| Aspirin 0541 | DISP | 197 | H Mart | ASPIR |
| Sildenafil 002 | VGRA | 12 | Omnicare | SILDE |
| Ibuprofen 378 | ADVL | 301 | Keystone | IBUPR |
| Paracetamol | PCTML | 673 | Walgreens | PARAC |
| Ibuprofen 1992 | ADVL | 87 | Omnicare | IBUPR |
| Sildenafil 1045 | VGRA | 45 | H Mart | SILDE |
| Benadryl | BDRL | 111 | Keystone | BENAD |
| Aspirin 9852 | DISP | 285 | CVS | ASPIR |
| Sildenafil 002 | VGRA | 79 | Rite Aid | SILDE |
| Aspirin 0541 | DISP | 431 | Omnicare | ASPIR |

And while that does uniformize the drugs, it's less helpful. Reading "VGRA" for ex. would be more helpful than reading "SILDE". How can I modify this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set the `Code` to the first observed `Code` value for each medicine:

```py
df['Code'] = df.groupby(df['Name'].str.split().str[0])['Code'].transform('first')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               Name   Code  Amount     Seller
0   Sildenafil 1045   VGRA      32   Rite Aid
1     Ibuprofen 378   ADVL     209        CVS
2       Paracetamol  PCTML      87   Keystone
3      Aspirin 9852   DISP     372   Rite Aid
4    Ibuprofen 1992   ADVL      87  Walgreens
5          Benadryl   BDRL     120        CVS
6      Aspirin 0541   DISP     197     H Mart
7    Sildenafil 002   VGRA      12   Omnicare
8     Ibuprofen 378   ADVL     301   Keystone
9       Paracetamol  PCTML     673  Walgreens
10   Ibuprofen 1992   ADVL      87   Omnicare
11  Sildenafil 1045   VGRA      45     H Mart
12         Benadryl   BDRL     111   Keystone
13     Aspirin 9852   DISP     285        CVS
14   Sildenafil 002   VGRA      79   Rite Aid
15     Aspirin 0541   DISP     431   Omnicare
```

Answer (score 0):

This question shares some similarities [with another I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226488/change-one-value-based-on-another-value-in-pandas), so I'd definitely recommend searching the archives.

#### Order-Agnostic Approach

###### I say order-agnostic because the other answer is ideal if you're looking to just use the 'first' value.

It seems like you're going to need a dict/hashmap that serves as your source of truth for re-defining the `Code` based on the `Name`. Given what you wrote in the question it would look something like this:

```
name_to_code_mapping = {"Ibuprofen": "ADVL", "Sildenafil": "...", ...}
```

You can then use the dict inside of a function that you can pass to something like [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def change_code_based_on_drug_name(df_row: pd.Series, column_to_find: str, column_to_change: str, map: dict):
    val_to_find = df_row[column_to_find]
    ## You'll have to split the numbers off of the name here
    trimmed_df_value = val_to_find.split(" ")[0]
    
    if trimmed_df_value in map:
        df_row[column_to_change] = map[trimmed_df_value]
    return df_row
```

And feed it to that `df.apply`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda row: change_code_based_on_drug_name(row, "Name", "Code", name_to_code_mapping), axis=1)
```

#### Alternative, Less Ideal Approach

You could also iterate over the map and use `.loc[]` (like in the above S/O post) to change the values but you would need to create a column of the name minus numbers:

```
## Notice that since I'm using apply over a single column (i.e. Series) here I don't need to axis paramter
df["Name_without_numbers"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda name: name.split(" ")[0])
```

You'd then set that to the index so you can use the `.loc` method.

```
df.set_index("Name_without_numbers", inplace=True)

for key, val in name_to_code_mapping.items():
    df.loc[key, "Code"] = val
```

I don't like or recommend that second approach because:

1. It adds an unnecessary column, and
2. Creates a non-unique index

Hope that helps!