# Python Pandas indexing

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

Sorry if this is a simple question, I've tried to look for a solution but can't find anything.

My code goes like this:

- given zip1, create an index to select observations (other zipcodes) where some calculation has not been done yet (666)

  ```
  I = (df['zip1'] == zip1) & (df['Distances'] == 666)
  ```
- perform some calculation

  ```
  distances = calc(zip1,df['zip2'][I])
  ```

So far so good, I've checked the distances variable, correct values, correct sized array.

- put the distance variable in the right place

  ```
  df['Distances'][I] = distances
  ```

but this last part updates all the `df['Distances']` variables to nonsense values FOR ALL observations with `df['zip1']=zip1` instead of the ones selected by `I`.

I've checked the boolean array `I` before the `df['Distances'][I] = distances` command and it looks fine.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `.loc` or `.ix` rather than chained assignment see [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) also [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869910/pandas-filter-rows-of-dataframe-with-operator-chaining) so the correct usage is `df.loc[l,'Distances']=distances`

Comment: do you have workging example to test?

Comment: The suggestion by EdChum worked.  Makes sense, never knew about this view vs copy stuff before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are attempting is called chained assignment and does not work the way you think as it returns a copy rather than a view hence the error you see.

There is more information about it [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and related [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869910/pandas-filter-rows-of-dataframe-with-operator-chaining), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125680/overriding-a-pandas-dataframe-column-with-dictionary-values-where-the-dictionar/19125721#19125721) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226488/python-pandas-change-one-value-based-on-another-value/19226617#19226617).

So you should either use `.loc` or `.ix` like so:

```
df.loc[I,'Distances']=distances
```